# random plancement issue three.js with for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random, three.js, mesh

I am trying to make a function that randomizes the placement of some clouds I imported, but the problem is, it generates the amount of clouds, but in the same position! I randomized the position, but when the code runs I have like 10 clouds in the same position. What can I do? this is the code:

```
loader.load('/clouds/clouds1/scene.gltf', function (clouds1) {


  var clouds1array = []
  function addClouds1(){

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      const clouds1Mesh = clouds1.scene
      const clouds1Position = clouds1Mesh.position
      clouds1Position.x = Math.random() * 10
      clouds1Position.y = Math.random() * 10
      clouds1Position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 300

      clouds1Mesh.scale.setX(0.05)
      clouds1Mesh.scale.setY(0.05)
      clouds1Mesh.scale.setZ(0.05)
      
  
      scene.add(clouds1Mesh)
      clouds1array.push(clouds1Mesh)
  
      
    }
    
  }

  
  addClouds1()
  
})
```

edit: clouds1.scene structure is this:[image]

I don't know why it has this amount of children, I tried to solve with the answer, but it still does not work. The 3rd child in the end contains the mesh, and I tried using that for it to work, but it says that I cannot use it in the `scene.add()` function

edit: I solved the problem! I just had to put the for loop outside the load function

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 30; i+= 3)

loader.load('/clouds/clouds1/scene.gltf', function (clouds1) {

 
 const cloud = clouds1.scene

 const child1 = clouds1.scene.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[2].children[0]


 child1.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ emissive: 'white', emissiveIntensity: 0.5})

 cloud.scale.set(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)

 cloud.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 500
 cloud.position.y = (Math.random() + ((Math.random() + 20 ) + 70))
 cloud.position.z = (Math.random() - 1) * 500

 cloud.rotation.x = Math.random()
 cloud.rotation.y = Math.random() 
 cloud.rotation.z = Math.random() 



 scene.add(cloud)


})
```

Comment: Note that the way you have it set up now, three.js will load one GLTF model per cloud. This will be fast because of browser caching, but is inefficient for memory. Some techniques you can investigate are: using `Object3D.clone()`, re-using geometry and materials across multiple meshes, and `InstancedMesh`.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thank you! I will. I'm new to programming so I kinda want to explore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GLTFLoader` results, which you have as `clouds1` is a generic object, from which you properly extract `clouds1.scene`. However, `clouds1.scene` is also a single `Scene` object. If you have 10 clouds in the GLTF model you loaded, then `clouds1.scene` will have 10 children, and you will need to loop through them like this:

```js
loader.load('/clouds/clouds1/scene.gltf', function (clouds1) {

  var clouds1array = []

  const clouds1Children = clouds1.scene.children

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

    const clouds1Mesh = clouds1Children[i]
    const clouds1Position = clouds1Mesh.position
    clouds1Position.x = Math.random() * 10
    clouds1Position.y = Math.random() * 10
    clouds1Position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 300

    clouds1Mesh.scale.setX(0.05)
    clouds1Mesh.scale.setY(0.05)
    clouds1Mesh.scale.setZ(0.05)
      
    scene.add(clouds1Mesh)
    clouds1array.push(clouds1Mesh)
  
  }
  
})
```

Comment: it returns this error: `main.js:200 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')
    at addClouds1 (main.js:200)`

Comment: @SaverioScagnoli I updated my answer. I removed the unnecessary function, and corrected a typo. If it still doesn't work, you will need to debug your code by placing a breakpoint on the first line of the callback. From there, you can inspect `clouds1` to see what it really contains. Update your question with any additional information you find about the structure of the `scene`.

Comment: edited :) thank you for your kind help.